# make Ubuntu search by default in all categories?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I am using Ubuntu 13.10. Every time I want to search for something using the <kbd>Super</kbd> key, Unity has set its search category (filter) for videos (nothing else), although I chose the last times to look for other categories like apps or documents. But Ubuntu changed my choice and enabled only searching for videos. Every time I want to search for something on my computer, I have to enable all filters. It is annoying!

Is there a way to make Ubuntu search by default in all categories?